# unable to use external command in tig

Tags: tig

I use git and gitk a lot. Recently, I found some enthousiastic posts about tig and decided to give it a try.
It looks great for viewing the repository, however changing the repo with tig seems difficult if not unworkable.

The problem I am facing is that tig fails to start an editor for external commands, thus making it impossible to continue with the action.
For example, if I select a commit and issue

```
!git commit --amend
```

I get a screen saying

```
vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal
```

Only ^C gets me out, thus stopping tig as well.

What can I do to configure this properly for either tig or git in order to get this working?

thanks in advance,
Ruud

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main way to start external commands is via keybindings and what in Tig is referred to as [user-defined commands](http://jonas.nitro.dk/tig/manual.html#commit-id). For example, to amend the last commit you can add the following to `~/.tigrc` after which pressing `+` will put you right into Vim:

```
bind generic + !git commit --amend
```

There are several variables for the browsing state, which can be passed to external commands, such as `%(commit)` and `%(branch)` as well as `%(prompt)` for asking for input, for example when creating a branch.

For reference, the `!<command>` allows to open the output in the pager, for example `!git show 3e3abcd` and as such is more like Vim's `:r!<command>`.

Comment: Hi @jonas, fantastic tool! Is binding to a key eg `bind main T !git tag %(prompt) %(commit)` and then pressing `T` supposed to function the same as invoking an external command directly, with a commit selected `:!git tag %(prompt) %(commit`?